# Preview all open documents

Tags: osx-mavericks

How can I use the keyboard on Mac-osx Mavericks to view all open Preview documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into System Preferences / Mission Control then use the keyboard combination it shows there for 'Application Windows'.  Change it there if you don't like the existing key combo.